# javafx perspective transform by dragging

Tags: java, javafx, transform, drag, perspective

i have a problem with javafx and the perspective transform effect. i want to be able to drag on one edge of a rectangle and be able to pull that edge. Up to here there is no problem. But i also want to transform the rectangle by the point i move, so that the point (the edge) will represent the location of perspective transform effect of that special edge. i hope you understand what i mean. i've searched a lot on google and tried some different solutions but it didn't work. so here is the code for my rectangle and also the points (which can be moved per mouse):

```
static double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    static double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

    private static int c_X_off = 0;
    private static int c_Y_off = 0;
    private static int c1_X_off = 0;
    private static int c1_Y_off = 0;
    private static int c2_X_off = 0;
    private static int c2_Y_off = 0;
    private static int c3_X_off = 0;
    private static int c3_Y_off = 0;

    public static void addRectangle(int X, int Y, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.setX(X);
        r.setY(Y);
        r.setWidth(WIDTH);
        r.setHeight(HEIGHT);
        r.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        r.setFill(Paint.valueOf("RED"));

        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
        r2.setX(X/2);
        r2.setY(Y/2);
        r2.setWidth(WIDTH/2);
        r2.setHeight(HEIGHT/2);
        r2.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        r2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        r2.setStrokeWidth(2);
        r2.setFill(Paint.valueOf("RED"));

        final PerspectiveTransform pt = new PerspectiveTransform();
        r2.setEffect(pt);

        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.setFill(Color.BLUE); c.setRadius(6); c.setCursor(Cursor.NW_RESIZE);
        c.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()-WIDTH/4); 
        c.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()-HEIGHT/4);

        Circle c1 = new Circle();
        c1.setFill(Color.BLUE); c1.setRadius(6); c1.setCursor(Cursor.NE_RESIZE);
        c1.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()+WIDTH/4); 
        c1.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()-HEIGHT/4);

        Circle c2 = new Circle();
        c2.setFill(Color.BLUE); c2.setRadius(6); c2.setCursor(Cursor.SE_RESIZE);
        c2.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()+WIDTH/4); 
        c2.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()+HEIGHT/4);

        Circle c3 = new Circle();
        c3.setFill(Color.BLUE);c3.setRadius(6); c3.setCursor(Cursor.SW_RESIZE);
        c3.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()-WIDTH/4); 
        c3.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()+HEIGHT/4);



        EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
                orgTranslateX = ((Rectangle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                orgTranslateY = ((Rectangle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

                ((Rectangle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                ((Rectangle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
                r.setTranslateX(newTranslateX * 2);
                r.setTranslateY(newTranslateY * 2);
                r.setX(newTranslateX * 2);
                r.setY(newTranslateY * 2);

                c.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()-WIDTH/4+c_X_off); 
                c.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()-HEIGHT/4+c_Y_off);

                c1.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()+WIDTH/4+c1_X_off); 
                c1.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()-HEIGHT/4+c1_Y_off);

                c2.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()+WIDTH/4+c2_X_off); 
                c2.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()+HEIGHT/4+c2_Y_off);

                c3.setTranslateX(r2.getTranslateX()-WIDTH/4+c3_X_off); 
                c3.setTranslateY(r2.getTranslateY()+HEIGHT/4+c3_Y_off);
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler2 = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
                orgTranslateX = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                orgTranslateY = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler2 = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

                ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);

                if(t.getSource().equals(c)) {
                    c_X_off = (int) offsetX;
                    c_Y_off = (int) offsetY;
                } else

                if(t.getSource().equals(c1)) {
                    c1_X_off = (int) offsetX;
                    c1_Y_off = (int) offsetY;
                } else

                if(t.getSource().equals(c2)) {
                    c2_X_off = (int) offsetX;
                    c2_Y_off = (int) offsetY;
                } else

                if(t.getSource().equals(c3)) {
                    c3_X_off = (int) offsetX;
                    c3_Y_off = (int) offsetY;
                }

                pt.setUlx(5);
                pt.setUly(5);
                pt.setUrx(5);
                pt.setUry(5);
                pt.setLrx(5);
                pt.setLry(5);
                pt.setLlx(5);
                pt.setLly(5);
            }
        };

        r2.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);
        r2.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);

        c.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler2);
        c.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler2);
        c1.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler2);
        c1.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler2);
        c2.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler2);
        c2.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler2);
        c3.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler2);
        c3.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler2);

        PrjMapper.addObject(r);

        PrjGui.root.getChildren().add(r2);
        PrjGui.root.getChildren().add(c);
        PrjGui.root.getChildren().add(c1);
        PrjGui.root.getChildren().add(c2);
        PrjGui.root.getChildren().add(c3);
        PrjGui.scene.setRoot(PrjGui.root);
    }
```

The rectangle and the circles are added to a StackPane of my gui and display. 
Why?
I'm trying to create a software for VideoMapping. If you need more from the code, please tell me!
Thanks a lot!

Paulee

Comment: I guess `PrjGui.root` is of type `StackPane` that is why the rectangle are added to the `StackPane`. Further your code block is overly long and not really usable for anyone here at SO to reproduce the issue. Please take a look at how to write a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I guess you didn't get me right. I don't really have an error, I need your help and this is the last try i did so java does what i want, but thanks for your answer! So for description: I have an rectangle and add 4 circles and snap them to 4 edges of the rectangle. How do I get the rectangle to be transformed to the circle position?
It's kind of hard to give you a full code for the "problem" since its spread over several classes but this is the main-part for the generation of the rectangle and circles and here the transision should take place! And yes, you're right, it is from type `StackPane`